# When was Transmetropolitan published?

Tags: comics, vertigo-comics, transmetropolitan

I know it was between 1997 and 2002, but when were specifically (date) put on sale the first and last single issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of the [main series](http://www.comicvine.com/transmetropolitan/49-5989/), the first issue has a [cover date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_date) of September 1997 and the last issue has a cover date of November 2002.

So July 1997 - September 2002 with the two month discrepancy.

On Comic Vine, issue #1 is marked September 1, 1997, and issue #60 November 1, 2002, but that is likely incorrect.

Comment: Oh drats, all their dates are marked 1st. That can't be right.